# Testing React components with Mocha: unexpected token

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I have my React components all fleshed out, and I wanted to learn how to test these components properly with Mocha + chai. I have these configurations for my `package.json` (relevant ones):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server",
    "build": "watchify main.js -t babelify -o bundle.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test/test*.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.6.23",
    "babelify": "^6.1.3",
    "browserify": "^11.0.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.8.3",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1"
},
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

I have `Skill.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'underscore';

export default class Skills extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>T E S T</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

along with a `test.js` in a folder called `test`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import Skills from '../src/components/Skills.js';
```

I'm receiving an unexpected token error when I run `npm test`.

[image]

What's the console complaining about? Why is the `<div>` tag not valid?

Comment: May be you need `"presets": ["react", "es2015"]`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and at first I thought I did not `import React from 'react';`.

Next I found out that I did not add `--require ./test/test_helper.js`

And last but then after still not working, it dawned on me that I did not restart node. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `babel-preset-es2015` before using it

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: I took your advice and added that dependency to `package.json`, but the same error is occurring.